# Access WP8 System Files

Tags: 8.0, nokia-lumia-920

Is there a way to access/explore (and more importantly, manipulate) WP8 system files either from a computer (Windows, Mac OSX, or preferably Linux) or from the phone itself?
What I am trying to achieve is access Whatsapp's auto backups and delete them. So, if there is a way to get around that without having to access the system file, please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to access the general file system of a Windows Phone 8 device, especially the storage used for each individual app.

The only access you have is to the [Documents, Music, Video, Ringtones and Pictures](http://winsupersite.com/article/windows-phone-8/windows-phone-8-tip-access-phones-file-system-144696) when your phone is plugged into a PC.

In the case of WhatsApp, [you should contact the developers](http://www.whatsapp.com/contact/) and ask for a feature to clear out old backups or export them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access the system files on Windows Phone. Also, whatsapp has no backup files (Not on the phone nor on it's servers). If you want to delete all your messaging data from the phone you have to reinstall whatsapp.

Comment: I've been deleting and reinstalling the app once every 15-20 days recently. So, if whatsapp doesn't keep backups, why is the size of the app increase dramatically? Whatsapp has almost taken up 400MB of my device storage already!

Comment: If this isn't because of images stored by whatsapp the best way is to send a bug report to the whatsapp devs. Given the space one character takes that should be around 100.000 pages of text which is unreasonable. This looks like there is duplicate data stored in whatsapp somewhere.

Comment: I do receive a lot of media files over whatsapp, but I clean all the records at least once a week. The size taken up on my device storage does NOT shrink down aftrward thou. My first guess was, the application is storing a back up of all the data (text, photos, audio notes, and videos) somewhere on my phone. Anyway, bug has been reported. Thanks :-)

Comment: At least photos are stored in the image hub in the saved images folder. Maybe take a look to see if all your media files are stored in that location.

Answer (score 0):

try the steps are in this youtube link, just copy paste system path using winRAR, when phone is connected to a windows pc -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j03Q6yEi6K0

Comment: can you list these steps inside your answer in case the link goes dead?